# What if BackgroundWorker control used massively?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, backgroundworker

I'm being afraid if a mass usage of `BackgroundWorker` control in a C# program will make the program slow and poorly responsible. So tell me if there is any such or any other problem if `BackgroundWorker` control used massively?

Comment: define massively.

Comment: Doing the same amount of work _without_ a BgW will certainly make your app slower and less responsive.

Comment: Maybe not slow and unresposive, but it will get way more complex when you have lots of threads running loose around inside your appliaction.

Comment: "massively" could be define as using a lot of different threads via more than one `BackGroundWorker`s.

Answer (score 2):

I think in general I wouldn't do heavy work in the UI thread.  You could create threads manually, but Microsoft already provided the BackgroundWorker, so I would definitely use that.  Whenever doing time-consuming tasks you should keep the user experience in mind.  Show them something to indicate work is occuring and provide progress if at all remotely possible.  You should also make the process cancellable so if the user wants to stop, they can.

Answer (score 1):

The Backgroundworker is just a wrapper for a (pool) Thread.

Creating lots of them in quick succession would follow the Threadpool rules: they will be queued and new threads will be created only slowly (2/sec) .

But a Bgw wrapper is useful for tying a short thread to the GUI (cancellation, progress reporting). It would be odd to have many of such tasks.

But Yes, starting very many BgWs and have them all running (blocking) for a considerable time would eventually create a lot of Threads and too many Threads will slow your program down.

Answer (score 0):

I have used around 25 BWs on a single form for a complex job-address + employee-address + working preferences scenario so far. Threading has always scared me. BWs works beautifully if the pattern is implemented properly. Of course, running 25 or more BWs simultaneously is a weird requirement. I just maintained a WorkerController (think ThreadPool) which was a Dictionary of TaskGuid and Task (BW). I just kept queuing tasks if current running BWs exceeded 10 at a time.

I'm now engaged with Task Parallel Library. I find it very flexible when it comes to rapid firing threads. Read [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). Also see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965237) to get an idea of TPL.